# Finding a path from node A to node B in a digraph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I'm trying to implement an algorithm to find a path between two nodes in a digraph which can have cycles.

I have readed a lot but I can't find anything that fits my requirements exactly (Dijkstra, Bellman–Ford, DFS, ...)

In my case, I have a function which gives me the following node (it can have different implementations) so, in the first version of my algorithm I just used that function to traverse the graph.

**The problem**, I can get blocked in a loop.

**Solution 1**: store nodes used and do not follow edges to that node.
This is not a good solution for me because I want to get into loops but not for infinite.

**Solution 2**: store edges used and do not use them twice. I can get into a loop but I can go out from an unused edge. But I still can get blocked if I have used all the edges which go out from a node and I reach that node again. I tried not to take into account used edges in this blocking situation but it's not a good solution because I can get into a llop for infinite (I think / not probed)

Now, I'm at the starting point and I want a good solution for my problem but I can't find it after some investigations.

My idea is to implement a DFS algorithm using a custom function to get the following node but I need to deal with the loop problem somehow.

Comment: I don't get the problem with solution 1. If you have the same node twice on a path you can always leave out the loop in between and still have a path from A to B.

Comment: Well if you are finding a path between two nodes A and B then if a path exists between them then there will always be a path without loops to reach from A to B. So when you encounter a loop you could discard that path.

Comment: I don't mind if I have loops, moreover I want the path to have loops.
So, solution 1 is not good to me (@Henry) and I don't want to discard loops (@Vinayak Singla)

Comment: Unless you graph edges have negative weights (in which case the best possible path could be infinitely long), Dijkstra or any other regular path-finding algorithm will work; they are designed to work on graphs with loops. If you don't have weights, assume each edge has a weight of 1. Take a look for example [here](https://visualgo.net/en/sssp) to see how it works.

Comment: If you want to allow loops, then you can first find all paths without loops, then all loops in the graph. For each path you can then add as many loops as you want.

Comment: I "do not" have weights, just a function which says which is the following node @jdehesa

But I want a DFS not a BFS to minimize time...

Comment: Please tell us more about why a standard BFS does not suit your needs. The removal of loops is only used for performance and does not change the first path found. How many paths do you want?

Comment: I just want the first path from node A to node B calculated using the function to get the next node. I don't want any improvement and I don't want to explore all the possible paths.

The problem is that using that function I can get into loops, so I need some way to break the loop.

An example: nodes A, B, C and D. edges A-C, C-D, D-A, C-B
Using the function I traverse A-C-D-A for infinite, so I need to break the loop and go from C to B.

Comment: @DavidAsensio Where did you get the idea that DFS is faster than BFS?

Comment: @fafl I´m not saying that, I say that I don´t want to optimize the path.

Comment: @DavidAsensio Can you describe what your graph looks like? How big is it, how many paths per node are there on average, how far are A and B apart from each other?